# Cycript from Jay Freeman Saurik I get a strange error while linking it to others programs

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia

I installed cycript, developed by Jay Freeman Saurik, on my device, I installed also all depencies dependencies.
I Run my mobileTerminal app on my device and I enter for example this command:

```
ps aux | grep MyProgram
```

I get the ID of the process but when I enter this command:

```
cycript -p [myProcessId]
```

But I get always this error.

```
*** _assert(_krnstatus == KERN_SUCCESS):Match/Inject.cpp(64):InjecLibrary [errno=78]
```

I'm using cycript on iOS 5. Is it compatible?

Comment: I'm getting `*** _assert(value != 0):Mach/Inject.cpp(62):nlset [errno=2]`. It looks like 'attach to process' is broken. Other tools like gdb attach fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you've already found an answer, but if you haven't, the answer is that you need to update to the latest version from the Cycript website to use it on iOS 5 - [here's the latest deb](http://www.cycript.org/debs/cycript_0.9.458_iphoneos-arm.deb) at the time I wrote this.

Also, you don't need to find out the process ID: you can just use `cycript -p MyProgram`.